# How to set a default ngOptions value, when options are objects, and default is an integer ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I'm working with ngOptions to display a select element, and want to connect the model to the value that's set as the value in ngOptions.

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope',
  function ($scope) {
    //Use random to simulate different data from an API
    $scope.default = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    $scope.options = [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "Option 1"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Option 2"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Option 3"
      }
    ];
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <select ng-model="default" ng-options="val.name for val in options track by val.id">
    </select>
    <pre>Default should be ID {{default}}, or Option {{default+1}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using `track by`, `select as`, and I've found two solutions that work, but are not ideal.

Ideally, I'd be able to set default

#### Solution 1:

```
// Loop through entire array of objects
$scope.options.forEach(function (v, k) {
  // Compare ID to what the default should be
  if (v.id === $scope.default) {
    // Set object to default
    $scope.default = v;
    return true;
  }
});
```

#### Solution 2:

**JS**

```
$scope.options = {
  "Option 1": 0,
  "Option 2": 1,
  "Option 3": 2
};
```

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="default" ng-options="value as key for (key, val) in options">
```

The thing that's tough about this solution is it only works if the object has no more than two values, since a key cannot be an object.

Is there any way to have Angular set a default by key, without having to include the entire object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this

```
<select ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in options" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

then in controller

```
$scope.selected = 1;
```

[similar plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/58shtDgq9Vr3A40MnWQr?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed. I guess I just messed up on the implemention of `as`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope',
  function ($scope) {
    //Use random to simulate different data from an API
    
    $scope.options = [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "Option 1"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Option 2"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Option 3"
      }
    ];
$scope.default = $scope.options[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <select ng-model="default" ng-options="val.name for val in options">
    </select>
    <pre>Default should be ID {{default.id}}, or Option {{default.id+1}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this does give the correct output, what I needed was to assign the value of `id` to `default` directly, instead of accessing it as a property.